# PagingLibrary Not Loading More data

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-paging

I am Using PagedList and PagedListAdapter and Using Room as DataBase. I am having 60 items in table but Adapter shows only 15 items(pageSize+ Prefetch distance). It is not loading more items after scrolling down or Up. I am using RxPagedListBuilder.

```
@Query("select * from table where id = :id ORDER BY id Asc ")
    fun getTable(id: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, Table>

val myPagingConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
    .setPageSize(5)
    .setPrefetchDistance(10)
    .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
    .build()

RxPagedListBuilder(dataSource,myPagingConfig)
    .buildFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    .subscribe({list->})
```

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Having the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure, all of your 60 items has the same id you provided in `getTable` method?